# Table Duplicate entry

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

**Health_risk table**

```
column 1 - PK - name 
column 2 - description
```

**Health_risk_components** table

```
column 1 - AI/PK - id 
column 2 - ingredient_name  
column 3 - FK - column1.name
```

For example, ill insert a row for first table.

Diabetes so id have multiple ingredients that are on watch for diabetes.

Naturally in table 2 would look like this.

> 1 - sugar - diabetes
>
> 2 - raisins - diabetes

But it errors duplicate entry for 3rd column which is the FK.

What i don understand is that i have a similar 3 table erd of my recipes.

> recipe - combinetable - ingredients

so naturally,

sunny side up assume 1 egg and oil.

On my recipe table id have sunny side up and its details etc.

> 1 - sunny side up

on my ingredients id have 2 entries

> 1 - egg
>
> 2 - oil

On my 3rd combine table would have 2 FK.

```
recipeid(FK) componentid(FK)
1                 1
1                 2
```

recipe id wil be inserted multiple times varying on the ingredients of each recipe. It does not duplicate entry error.

Comment: Do you by chance have a Unique index on Column 3 of Health_Risks_components table?

Comment: Can you show the tables DDL ? and is it Sql-Server or MySql ???

Comment: Yes, its a unique index.

Come to think of it. im using phpmyadmin, in order to make a foreign key i need to index it right? lemme check if there are any other index available.

Comment: like what you did wrong FK, show DDL please

Comment: There is an option that is just `index`.  You do not want `Unique`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you set the Foreign key on `column 3` of `Health_risk_components` to be a `UNIQUE` index instead of just an `index`.  If it is listed as unique then that value has to be unique from all other rows in that column.

Try the following queries to remove the unique index and add the right index:

```
ALTER TABLE Health_risk_components DROP INDEX column_3;
ALTER TABLE Health_risk_components ADD INDEX (  `column_3` )
```